# how to add section Scripts to asp.net mvc Razor View without layout page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My mvc view layout is null. how can i add script inside view.

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtChild1').on('change', function () {
             $("#C1Age1").show();
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

Error show

> cannot resolve section 'Scripts'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If  you use `Layout = null` then you don't need to use `@section Scripts` any more. you can simply use script tag.

**Example:**

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtChild1').on('change', function () {
             $("#C1Age1").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using layout page then you need not to add section. add scripts as you add them on a html page.

```
@{
   Layout = null;
 }
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtChild1').on('change', function () {
             $("#C1Age1").show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add script block without section if it is not mandatory.